# WP3.8 back end - radio button doesn't be selected

Tags: css, wordpress

It may be a very minor thing, but a *problem* to me now.

I made a custom meta box on the post edit page in the WP back end, where I put two radio buttons saying "Yes" and "No". If the "Yes" radio button is selected, then on save the post will save a meta data with "Featured". By default the radio button will be on "No", because no post is Featured yet.

I checked with Inspect Element, when I opened a new post to write, my code's working well:

```
<input name="insert_featured_post" id="insert_featured_post" type="radio" value="yes">Yes
<input name="insert_featured_post" id="insert_featured_post" type="radio" value="no" selected="selected">No
```

But by default, no radio button is showing selected, not even the "No" one. ([image: no button is seleted])

If I click on the "Yes" one, it's working, and the radio button is visible too. If I save the post, it's working well and saving it's value "Featured".

If I reopen a Featured Post to edit, by default the "Yes" should be highlighted, but no button is highlighted, but using Inspect Element, I saw that, the "Yes" button is highlighted.

How could I solve this UI problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For radio-buttons is `checked` attribute for default value, not `selected`, change `selected="selected"` to `checked="checked"`.